# Finding the equation of a circle and a tangent line to the circle given two end points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles

> Given the endpoints $(11, 23)$ and $(6, 13)$ of a circle, find the equation of the circle and the equation of a line tangent to the circle.

First, I found the center using the midpoint formula:

$$ \left(\frac{11+6}{2}, \frac{13+23}{2}\right)$$
$$\left(\frac{17}{2}, 18\right)$$

Then I found the radius by finding the distance between the points and dividing by 2:

$$\frac{\sqrt{(13 - 23)^2 + (6 - 11)^2}}{2} = \frac{5\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

The equation:

$$(x - 17/2)^2 + (y - 18)^2 = \left(\frac{5\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2$$

How can I find an equation tangent to this? I tried finding the slope between $(11, 23)$ and $(6, 13)$, finding the negative reciprocal, and plugging in one of the points into the point slope form, but when I graphed it, the line wasn't tangent to the circle.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why it asks for **the** tangent line. Because there's not just one.

Comment: Right... I edited it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you should find the tangent line at the two given points $(11, 23)$ and $(6, 13)$: Since they are endpoints of a diameter of the circle, the slopes of the tangent lines to the circle at each point, respectively, will be equal (they will be parallel).

The slope of the line *connecting them* will thus be *perpendicular to the tangent lines* at those points.

So find the slope of the line connecting the two given points. Call it $m$. We see $\quad m = \dfrac{23-10}{11 - 5} = 2$

The slope of the lines tangent to the circle at the given points will then be $-\dfrac 1m = -\dfrac 12$.

Then you can find both the equation of the line tangent to the circle at $(11, 23)$, and the equation of the line tangent to the circle at $(6, 13)$, using the point-slope form for the equation of a line. E.g., the tangent to the circle at $(6, 13)$ will be $$y - 13 = -\dfrac 12(x - 6) \iff y = -\dfrac 12 x + 16\qquad\qquad\tag{tangent line at $(6, 13)$}$$

Indeed, the process outlined above sounds like what you tried, so I suspect you made an error somewhere in your calculation of slope, or forming the equation of one of the tangent lines:

Graphing both the circle and the equation of the line given above in Wolfram Alpha gives this nice [tangent to the circle](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%20-%2017/2%29%5E2%20%2b%20%28y%20-%2018%29%5E2%20=%20%28%285%2a%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%29/2%29%5E2,%20y%20=%20-%281/2%29x%20%2b%2016)

Comment: Nice descriptions and a slow night indeed! + 1

Answer (score 2):

The simplest tangent lines would be horizontal or vertical.  Try looking for those.

Answer (score 1):

As vadim123 said, finding the horizontal and vertical tangent lines is trivial. To find any tangent line on the circle, take the derivative of the parametric equations: and divide them to find the slope of a tangent line:
$$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$$
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}x=-sin(\theta)$$
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}y=cos(\theta)$$
$$m = -\frac{cos(\theta)}{sin(\theta)}$$

here $\theta$ can be any angle. To find $x_1$ and $y_1$, use the same angle $\theta$ and plug it into $x=\frac{5\sqrt{5}}{2}cos(\theta)+17/2$ and $y=\frac{5\sqrt{5}}{2}sin(\theta)+17/2$.

Comment: As you can see, $tan$ is called the tangent function for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Using vadim's idea: You know that the center is at $(17/2, 18)$, and the radius is $5\sqrt5/2$. So, the point $(17/2, 18 + 5\sqrt5/2)$ is at the "top" of the circle. The tangent at this point is horizontal; it is the line $y = 18 + 5\sqrt5/2$.

Answer (score 0):

The chords from the endpoints of a diameter of a circle to any other point on the circle form a right angle. Two nonzero vectors are at right angles to each other iff their dot product vanishes. These two facts allow one to immediately write an equation for a circle given the endpoints $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ of a diameter: $$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)+(y-y_1)(y-y_2)=0.\tag{*}$$ If you need to put this in the more familiar form $(x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2=r^2$, it’s a simple enough matter to find the midpoint of the diameter, as you have done, and then rearrange (*) accordingly.

You can also find an equation of tangent line to this circle almost mechanically: if $P=(x_p,y_p)$ is a point on the circle with equation $(x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2=r^2$, then an equation for the tangent at $P$ is $(x_p-x_c)(x-x_c)+(y_p-y_c)(y-y_c)=r^2$. If your equation is in the more general form $x^2+y^2+ax+by+c=0$, there’s a slightly more complicated substitution that you can make to convert it into an equation for the tangent at $P$: $$x^2\to xx_p, y^2\to yy_p, x\to\frac12(x+x_p), y\to\frac12(y+y_p).$$ (This substitution, with one more rule for the $xy$ term, works for the general equation of *any* conic, in fact.)

Either way, since you’ve already found an equation for your circle and know two points on it, finding an equation for the tangent at either of those points is a straightforward matter of substitution and simplification.

---

If you’re comfortable working with matrices, you can also use the fact that the polar of a point on a circle is the tangent at that point. Without going into details, this means that an equation of the tangent at $P$ is $$\begin{bmatrix}x&y&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1&0&-x_c\\0&1&-y_c\\-x_c&-y_c&x_c^2+y_c^2-r^2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_p\\y_p\\1\end{bmatrix}=0,$$ but this amounts to making the substitution into the circle’s equation that I described above. (This works for *any* conic, in fact.)